# How to use rendered template in creating a pdf

Tags: pdf, go

Ok so I am Go Lang with the Echo framework, to try and build pdf which will load data from a database source - that bit will come later.

So this is how I am rendering my `pdf html` layout,

```
func (c *Controller) DataTest(ec echo.Context) error {
  return ec.Render(http.StatusOK, "pdf.html", map[string]interface{}{
    "name": "TEST",
    "msg":  "Hello, XXXX!",
  })
}
```

The above function works fine, and renders the html (I built a temp path to the function). Now I want to use that function as my html template to build my pdf's.

So I am using `wkhtmltopdf` and the lib `"github.com/SebastiaanKlippert/go-wkhtmltopdf"`

This is how I would render the html in the pdf,

```
html, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./assets/pdf.html")

if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

But I need to be able to update the template so that is why I am trying to render the page and take that into the pdf.

However, the Echo framework returns an error type and not of type bytes or strings and I am not sure how to update it so my rendered content is returned as bytes?

Thanks,

UPDATE

```
page := wkhtmltopdf.NewPageReader(bytes.NewReader(c.DataTest(data)))
```

This is how I am currently doing, the data is just a html string which is then turned into a slice of bytes for the `NewReader`.

This works fine, but I wanted to turn the `DataTest` function into a fully rendered html page by Echo. The problem with that is that when you return a rendered page, it is returned as an error type.

So I was trying to work out a why of updating it, so I could return the data as an html string, which would then be put in as a slice of bytes.

Comment: please include your error message as it is hard to understand what you are trying to say. Error messages are usually very straightforward. If it is erroring because it expects strings but getting bytes then all you have to do is cast it to string like `string(yourbytes)`

Comment: Please add more examples to your question, `ioutil.ReadFile` doesn't render the html in the pdf...

Comment: I think the solution is very simple. But some important informations are missing. If you render it on the server you could just use the pdf API by calling the rendered html from the server with `page := NewPage("https://url/to/your/page/?rid=12342")` or why is this not possible? How do you handle the template? Show where you parse and execute it. Why you read a file? Is that the template or the rendered html?

Comment: @apxp thats is something I could do. I was trying to use the function without adding it to my router.

Comment: There are no errors, as its the wrong type. I have updated my question with some more information

Comment: You know that the method `DataTest()` returns just an error interface at `bytes.NewReader(c.DataTest(data))`? So the `NewReader()` call can not work.

Answer (score 1):

if you want rendered html, use echo' custom middleware. I hope it helps you.

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "io"
    "net"

    "net/http"

    "github.com/labstack/echo"
)

type TemplateRegistry struct {
    templates map[string]*template.Template
}

func (t *TemplateRegistry) Render(w io.Writer, name string, data interface{}, c echo.Context) error {
    tmpl, ok := t.templates[name]
    if !ok {
        err := errors.New("Template not found -> " + name)
        return err
    }
    return tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "base.html", data)
}

func main() {
    e := echo.New()

    templates := make(map[string]*template.Template)
    templates["about.html"] = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("view/about.html", "view/base.html"))
    e.Renderer = &TemplateRegistry{
        templates: templates,
    }

    // add custom middleware
    // e.Use(PdfMiddleware)

    // only AboutHandler for Pdf
    e.GET("/about", PdfMiddleware(AboutHandler))

    // Start the Echo server
    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":8080"))
}

// custom middleware
func PdfMiddleware(next echo.HandlerFunc) echo.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c echo.Context) (err error) {
        resBody := new(bytes.Buffer)
        mw := io.MultiWriter(c.Response().Writer, resBody)
        writer := &bodyDumpResponseWriter{Writer: mw, ResponseWriter: c.Response().Writer}
        c.Response().Writer = writer

        if err = next(c); err != nil {
            c.Error(err)
        }

        // or use resBody.Bytes()
        fmt.Println(resBody.String())
        return
    }
}

type bodyDumpResponseWriter struct {
    io.Writer
    http.ResponseWriter
}

func (w *bodyDumpResponseWriter) WriteHeader(code int) {
    w.ResponseWriter.WriteHeader(code)
}

func (w *bodyDumpResponseWriter) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
    return w.Writer.Write(b)
}

func (w *bodyDumpResponseWriter) Flush() {
    w.ResponseWriter.(http.Flusher).Flush()
}

func (w *bodyDumpResponseWriter) Hijack() (net.Conn, *bufio.ReadWriter, error) {
    return w.ResponseWriter.(http.Hijacker).Hijack()
}

func AboutHandler(c echo.Context) error {
    return c.Render(http.StatusOK, "about.html", map[string]interface{}{
        "name": "About",
        "msg":  "All about Boatswain!",
    })
}
```

**view/about.html**

```
{{define "title"}}
  Boatswain Blog | {{index . "name"}}
{{end}}

{{define "body"}}
  <h1>{{index . "msg"}}</h1>
  <h2>This is the about page.</h2>
{{end}}
```

**view/base.html**

```
{{define "base.html"}}
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>{{template "title" .}}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      {{template "body" .}}
    </body>
  </html>
{{end}}
```

Comment: This looks good. I give this a good when I can, I am just using a string for now. But your setting this up to use a URL, which would make the function accessible by anyone with that route. That is something I dont want. I am looking for a function that does not go though a router and can be called within another function. Therefore i am not sure if the middleware would work? Has I think that would only work for route functions?

Comment: If you want to apply middleware to only one API, you can do it as an example. I updated the example.

Answer (score 0):

So from what I understand you want to:

1. Render HTML from template
2. Convert HTML to PDF
3. Send it as an HTTP response? This part is unclear from your question, but it doesn't matter really.

So, the reason Echo returns `error` is because it actually not only does the template rendering, but also sending a response to client. If you want to do something else in-between, you can't use that method from echo.

Luckily, echo doesn't do anything magical there. You can just use the standard template package with the same result.

```
func GetHtml(filename string, data interface{}) (string, error) {
    filedata, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    asString := string(filedata)
    t, err := template.New("any-name").Parse(asString)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    var buffer bytes.Buffer
    err = t.Execute(&buffer, data)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    return buffer.String(), nil
}
```

There you have your function that returns a `string`. You can use `buffer.Bytes()` to have a byte array if that's preferrable.

After this you can do whatever you need to, like convert to PDF and write it back to clients using `echoCtx.Response().Writer()`.

Hope that helps, but in future try asking more precise questions, then you are more likely to receive an accurate response.

Comment: I am not sure what your data var is doing? In my DataTest (1st version) I returned a rendered html page (by Echo) with also includes a map of data sent into the template to add to the content. What I have done so far is to just render a string html (update DataTest). While on the PDF plugins github page, there is a way to render a open file, what is not what I want. I need it to be rendered, e.g. content added into the template and that template passed back to me as a string / slice of bytes

Comment: @C0ol_Cod3r data is the parameters for your template. Please see https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/